# Is it possible to add adverts in the posts widget in Elementor?

Tags: elementor

Is it possible to modify the query of a posts widget in Elementor to inject and advert every nth element?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically, I have a grid of 2 x 6 posts of a specific query, e.g. category + tags and I would like to inject and advert at position number 6 of the grid.